# Как вставить скопированный текст в поле Entry в python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Я создаю простую программу для загрузки видео с YouTube на python с использованием tkinter. Там имеется виджет - текстовое поле Entry, в которое нужно вставить текст из буффера обмена. Однако не нажатие ПКМ, не CTRL + V не позволяет вставить его.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы текст из буфера обмена можно было вставить в текстовое поле?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Горячие клавиши работают, но только в английской раскладке.

Comment: @insolor Действительно работает... Спасибо. Я даже не додумался раскладку поменять

Answer (score 0):

Используй этот код, при нажатии кнопки выводит сохраненный в буфере текст.

```
import tkinter
import pyperclip


root = tkinter.Tk()
def func():
    entry.insert(0, pyperclip.paste)
entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
btn = tkinter.Button(text='paste', command=func).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Окей, спасибо !